# How do I create a Java EE container deployable JAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, ejb

I have a main project used as a standalone batch that I want to move to the container using EJB timer (using WildFly 8.2). I thought building a WAR file with the timer class and the dependencies withing WEB-INF/lib, but doesn't sound an elegant solution because it isn't a web app, it doesn't need to bound a context. It's just a JAR, with an EJB inside and the dependencies (I'm using a fat jar) but the container throws an error when I deploy it. Should I use an EAR? Or do you guys think a WAR file is fine?
PS: I'm using Maven, so possible suggestions can take it in account.

Comment: Before make your project as WAR, did you try `ejb` packaging?

Comment: To be honest I dont know about this packaging, gonna search about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need it in a WAR file if it's not a web application, although it doesn't harms. I would also put it in a JAR file, i don't like to add something that doesn't have a meaning...it can be confusing for others. But as @Bruno César pointed out, you need to *package* first the EJB(s). Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipnz/index.html); you'll see the ways to package them as JAR, WAR, EAR.

Answer (score 0):

EJB package is good solution if your standalone application has no any third party libraries. But if it has, then best solution would be EAR package type.